# How come my css snap scrolling works on my phone but not my computer?

Tags: html, css

I have a container (SkillsBar) with some items (Skill) in there. I have made it so that you can scroll (in the x-direction) once the page hits a certain width. Then I made it so that when you scroll it snaps to each individual item in the container, but for some reason, when testing it on my computer, the snap scrolling works, but the items snap to a place that is slightly off center, but on my phone it looks perfect. I am using a localhost as well to test this.

HTML:

```
    <div class="SkillsBar">

        <div class="Skill">
            <h2><i class="fa-brands fa-java"></i></h2>
            <p>Java</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Skill">
            <h2><i class="fa-brands fa-html5"></i></h2>
            <p>HTML</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Skill">
            <h2><i class="fa-brands fa-css3-alt"></i></h2>
            <p>CSS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Skill">
            <h2><i class="fa-brands fa-python"></i></h2>
            <p>Python</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Skill">
            <h2><i class="fa-solid fa-file-excel"></i></h2>
            <p>Excel</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Skill">
            <h2><img src="images/Matlab_Logo.png" alt="MATLAB"></h2>
            <p>MATLAB</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Skill">
            <h2><img src="images/soldiworks2.png" alt="SolidWorks"></h2>
            <p>Solidworks</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.SkillsBar {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.Skill {
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translateY(0);  /* IDK why this needs to be here but it does*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 910px) {

    .SkillsBar {
        height: 125px;
        background-color: red;
        scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
        scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    
    .Skill {
        min-width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: green;
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }

    .SkillsBar::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

Ive just tried playing around with what I have right now and adding and deleting some things to see what could be causing the issue. The only thing I have noticed is that this needs to be here for the snapping to even work at all:

```
    .Skill {
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.Skill {
    scroll-snap-align: center;
}
```